# When I use topi.nn.upsampling I have an error InternalError

Tags: tvm

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tvm
from tvm import te
from tvm import autotvm
from tvm import topi
from vta.top.utils import is_packed_layout
from vta.environment import get_env




@autotvm.register_topi_compute("upsampling_packed.vta")
def upsampling(
    cfg,
    data,
    scale_h,
    scale_w,
    layout="NCHW",
    method="nearest_neighbor",
    align_corners=False,
    output_shape=None,
):
    env = get_env()
    batch, channels, in_height, in_width, in_batch, in_channels   = data.shape
    data_shape = data.shape
    out_height = int(in_height.value * scale_h)
    out_width = int(in_width.value * scale_w)
    # data_buf = te.compute(
    #     data_shape, 
    #     # lambda b_o, c_o, i, j, b_i, c_i:data[b_o, c_o, i, j, b_i, c_i].astype(env.acc_dtype),
    #     lambda *i: data(*i).astype(env.acc_dtype),
    #     name="data_buf",
    #     tag="data_buf"
    # ) # inp_scope
    # output = te.compute(
    #     (batch, channels, out_height, out_width, in_batch, in_channels),
    #     lambda b_o, c_o, i, j, b_i, c_i: data[b_o, c_o, te.round(te.floordiv(i, scale_h)).astype(env.acc_dtype), te.round(te.floordiv(j, scale_w)).astype(env.acc_dtype), b_i, c_i],
    #     # .astype(env.out_dtype), # 因为直接展示的int32的数据导致出现了后面数据全部为0的情况，请数据返回类型改为out_dtype就可以解决
    #     name="upsampling_packed",
    #     tag="upsampling_packed",
    # )

    output =  topi.nn.upsampling(
            # data_buf,
            data,
            scale_h=scale_h,
            scale_w=scale_w,
            layout=layout,
            method=method,
            align_corners=align_corners,
           # output_shape=( batch, channels, out_height, out_width)
    )
    output = te.compute(
        (batch, channels, out_height, out_width, in_batch, in_channels),
        lambda *i: output(*i) + 0, # 因为直接展示的int32的数据导致出现了后面数据全部为0的情况，请数据返回类型改为out_dtype就可以解决
        name="upsampling_add",
        tag="upsampling_add",
    ) # acc_scope 
    output = te.compute(
        (batch, channels, out_height, out_width, in_batch, in_channels),
        # lambda b_o, c_o, i, j, b_i, c_i: output[b_o, c_o, i, j, b_i, c_i].astype(env.out_dtype), # 因为直接展示的int32的数据导致出现了后
         lambda *i: output(*i).astype(env.out_dtype),
        # 面数据全部为0的情况，请数据返回类型改为out_dtype就可以解决
        name="upsampling_res",
        tag="upsampling_res",
    )
    return output

@autotvm.register_topi_schedule("upsampling_packed.vta")
def schedule_upsampling_packed(cfg, outs, layout=None):
    # assert layout == "NCHW", "Only NCHW layout is supported for upsampling"
    assert len(outs) == 1
    
    env = get_env()
    output = outs[0]# output 是待优化的计算张量。
    const_ops = []
    ewise_inputs = []
    ewise_ops = []
    upsample_res = []
    assert "int" in output.op.input_tensors[0].dtype


    # _traverse(output.op)    

    # data_buff_op = output.op.input_tensors[0].op.input_tensors[0].op.input_tensors[0] #  data_buff_add
    resize_op = output.op.input_tensors[0].op.input_tensors[0]
    upsample_packed = output.op.input_tensors[0]
    # print(f'data_buff_op:{data_buff_op}')
    print(f'resize_op:{resize_op}')
    print(f'upsample_packed:{upsample_packed}')

    
    batch, channels, in_height, in_width, batch_inner, channels_inner  = output.shape
    # # Create schedule
    s = te.create_schedule(output.op)
    # # # # Reorder axes
    bo, co, h, w, bi, ci= s[resize_op].op.axis
    cfg.define_split("tile_bo", bo, num_outputs=2)
    cfg.define_split("tile_co", co, num_outputs=2)
    cfg.define_split("tile_h", h, num_outputs=2)
    cfg.define_split("tile_w", w, num_outputs=2) 
    cfg.define_split("title_bi", bi, num_outputs=2) 
    cfg.define_split("tile_ci", ci, num_outputs=2)
    cfg.define_knob("oc_nthread", [1, 2])
    cfg.define_knob("h_nthread", [1, 2])

    x_bo, x_co, x_h, x_w, x_bi, x_ci = s[output].op.axis
    x_co0, x_co1= cfg["tile_co"].apply(s, output, x_co)
    x_i0, x_i1 = cfg["tile_h"].apply(s, output, x_h)
    x_j0, x_j1 = cfg["tile_w"].apply(s, output, x_w)
    s[output].reorder(x_bo, x_i0, x_co0,  x_j0, x_co1, x_i1, x_j1, x_bi, x_ci)
    store_pt = x_i0
    # # x_co0
    # # x_i0
    
    # s[data_buff_op].set_scope(env.acc_scope)
    s[resize_op].set_scope(env.acc_scope)
    s[upsample_packed].set_scope(env.acc_scope)
    
    
    x_co0_, x_co1_= cfg["tile_co"].apply(s, resize_op, co)
    x_i0_, x_i1_ = cfg["tile_h"].apply(s, resize_op, h)
    x_j0_, x_j1_ = cfg["tile_w"].apply(s, resize_op, w)      
    s[resize_op].reorder(bo, x_i0_, x_co0_, x_j0_, x_co1_, x_i1_, x_j1_, bi, ci)



    # s[data_buff_op].compute_at(s[upsample_packed], x_i0_)
    s[resize_op].compute_at(s[output], store_pt)
    s[upsample_packed].compute_at(s[output], store_pt)
    
    # s[data_buff_op].pragma(s[data_buff_op].op.axis[0], env.dma_copy)
    s[resize_op].pragma(bi, env.dma_copy)
    s[upsample_packed].pragma(s[upsample_packed].op.axis[0], env.alu)


    # # store_out = env.dma_copy
    # # # 需要在将结果拷贝到dram上之前，将计算结果拷贝的output_memory (有inp_memory， acc_memory ,wgt_memory, output_memory 
    s[output].pragma(x_bi, env.dma_copy)
    
    return s
```

0: tvm::tir::CopyIntrinInjector::VisitStmt_(tvm::tir::AttrStmtNode const*)
at /home/lay/tvm/src/tir/transforms/inject_copy_intrin.cc:51
resize[i3_outer * 32 + i5] = T.Cast("int32", T.Cast("float32", data[T.max(T.min(T.Cast("int32", T.round(T.float32(0.48936170339584351) * T.Cast("float32", i2_outer))), 23), 0) * 768 + T.max(T.min(T.Cast("int32", T.round(T.float32(0.48936170339584351) * T.Cast("float32", i3_outer))), 23), 0) * 32 + i5]))
i2_outer = T.int32()
data = T.Buffer((18432,), "int32")
i3_outer = T.int32()
resize = T.Buffer((1536,), "int32", scope="local.acc_buffer", align=32)
File "/home/lay/tvm/src/tir/transforms/inject_copy_intrin.cc", line 51
InternalError: Check failed: (MatchCopyPattern(op->body, &ret, &error_info)) is false: Cannot match copy pattern. The error is the 'BufferLoadNode' of body is a nullptr. The body is for i5 in range(32):

I'm using my own te.compute, but that creates a lot of stored instructions.

```
    output = te.compute(
        (batch, channels, out_height, out_width, in_batch, in_channels),
        lambda b_o, c_o, i, j, b_i, c_i: data[b_o, c_o, te.round(te.floordiv(i, scale_h)).astype(env.acc_dtype), te.round(te.floordiv(j, scale_w)).astype(env.acc_dtype), b_i, c_i],
        # .astype(env.out_dtype), # 因为直接展示的int32的数据导致出现了后面数据全部为0的情况，请数据返回类型改为out_dtype就可以解决
        name="upsampling_packed",
        tag="upsampling_packed",
    )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.